# why does the memory usage grows after each page load of same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a simple view to show around 2000 customers (not yet paged, which is the next step in my process).

This is my controller part:

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyModel _context;

    public CustomersController(MyModel context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
 // GET: Customers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var customers = await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
        return View(customers);
    }

}
```

and a simple view:

```html
@model IEnumerable<Customer>

  @{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
      </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Whenever I refresh the page (returning the same resultset), the process memory grows with 20 to 30 MB each time.

Below a screenshot of the memory diagnostics:
snapshot 1 is before the first page load; 
snapshot 2 is after the first page load; 
snapshot 3 is after tens of reloads of that same page...

[image: memory diagnostic]

I would think that the memory would stay the same, because the DbContext should be disposed of at each request, no?

What am I doing wrong and how can I control the memory usage?

[EDIT]

So, it appears that GC should kick in after a while. This screenshot shows it: part before first GC is a lot of consecutive loads of the same page (Customers). between the first and the second GC another page (Products) was loaded multiple times (not causing any memory rise?). After the third GC memory drops a bit, but is still "freigthening" high IMHO...

[image]

Comment: When I've used a mapper in the past, I have had issues mapping against an `IEnumerable`. It's sometimes executed the query more than once. Try using SQL Server Profiler to see if it has ran more than once. I wrote an article containing SQL Server Profiler here: https://www.roundthecode.com/server-side-development/tools-to-improve-slow-sql-queries-in-sql-server

Comment: with every refresh, the query is done once. The query is: `SELECT [dtoCustomer].[City], [dtoCustomer].[CompanyName], [dtoCustomer].[Id], [dtoCustomer].[Name]
FROM [Customers] AS [dtoCustomer]`

Comment: The [Visual Studio memory usage profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage) might help you see what's going on.

Comment: @stuartd , see the added screenshot...

Comment: Is `MyModel` actually getting disposed? Have you tried temporarily removing the mapper from the equation just to see if the behavior changes? Just return raw Customers instead of your dto.

Comment: @mxmissile How can I check if the context is disposed? And, am I right to say that memory usage should drop after disposing the context?
I have tried without the mapper and it gives the same result (I edited my question)

Comment: The garbage collector isn't going to run until it needs to.  Disposing the context isn't going to result in an immediate garbage collection.  I don't think you have anything to worry about; rather, I see no cause for concern.  You're hydrating some objects each time you run your query.  That memory usage will remain until the GC collects it.

Comment: you need to see what's been retained.

Comment: @Amy is right, I think if you keep hitting the page, you will see the memory usage calm down

Comment: @Amy, so after a while I should see GC kick in and memory usage should drop? let me try that

Comment: @intrixius Yes, I expect that as you continue to use your page, the memory usage will climb until the GC activates and cleans up.  Then you'll see a drop, and it will start to rise again.  The graph will look like a roller coaster.  .Net is designed to use as much memory as it needs, and activates the GC when it predicts the need to clean up memory.  In practice, I've found there's rarely a need to concern myself with the GC.  I think you have nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: @amy, ok, that sounds reasonable, but still a bit freightening. I thought that memory consumption should always be kept as low as possible...
I will add a screenshot of a longer period where GC kicks in...

Comment: @intrixius No, garbage collection *can be* an expensive (in CPU-time) process that introduces noticible latency in performance testing.  The GC tries to run infrequently, only when it needs to.  You might review [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) to better understand how and when the GC works.

Comment: @intrixius I see your edit, but I still see no cause for concern.  It's only alarming if the GC works to keep memory at a minimum, but that isn't what it does.  It works to keep memory *available* by moving objects around in memory and freeing up space.  It's not going to try freeing up as much as possible.  It's only going to free up what it needs to ensure that future memory allocations can succeed.

Comment: @Amy, thanks for explaining! I misunderstood the concept of GC and memory usage completely...

Comment: If my comments satisfactorily answered your question, I can type up an equivalent answer.

Comment: @amy, it did and I will accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have some misconceptions on what the garbage collectors purpose is.  It's purpose is not to *minimize* memory usage; rather, it's to ensure your process has memory *available*.  It's an important distinction.

The garbage collector will periodically sweep memory for objects that are no longer in use and mark them for collection.  Later, when the GC detects that it is running low on memory, it will activate and:

1. Move things around, so you have fewer small blocks of memory and more larger blocks of memory (memory can only be allocated in contiguous blocks).
2. Collect objects and free up their memory.

It will run infrequently. This can be configured to tailor the GC to specific requirements, though this is rarely required.  Each time the GC runs, it will do as little as possible to ensure your program has the memory it needs.  It does this because garbage collection is *expensive*, and can result in noticeable performance spikes.

Disposing an object does not mean "immediately get rid of this and free up its memory".  It means "I'm not using this anymore, so you can clean it up at your convenience." (software is so polite!)  So, disposing of your context won't result in an immediate reduction of memory usage.  It is possible to give a very strong hint to the GC that you *want* a collection, but its rarely needed and not advised.

So, your GC will wait. It will bide its time until it detects "hey, we're running low on memory!" Then, and only then, will it inspect your process for unreachable objects for collection.

So, you can expect the GC to run when your memory consumption begins to exceed the memory available to the process.  Then, it will free memory as quickly as possible.  It's goal is only to ensure your process *has memory available*.

So, what can you expect to observe?

1. Your processes memory will go up and down like a roller coaster.  It will go up more frequently than it goes down.
2. Your process memory usage will trend toward the maximum available memory, and will generally only go down as it approaches the limit.
3. Collections will be infrequent (as needed) and can vary wildly in size.

I do not think you have anything to be concerned about, and recommend you only worry about your memory usage if you start getting out-of-memory errors.

Comment: Thanks! This really took away my concerns about memory usage that I already have since months!

Comment: will caching these requests improve memory usage (and speed)? If so, where should I look into to get started with caching?

Comment: @intrixius Possibly, possibly not.  Caching is, by its nature, keeping a copy of the data in memory.  Each time you use that cache data, you'll be making a copy of it, then sending it off.  Those copies will still be garbage collected.  You generally cache to optimize for speed, not memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to know how some parts of your code really behave, I recommend you to use https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet
You can actually see how memory usage and GC collections will look like with MemoryDiagnoser.
I recommend to use GcMode Server to be TRUE as it will show you better how GC will work on server and not on local workstation.
I know it is a hussle to learn how to use it, but it is well worth after some time.

Trouble with looking at the memory usage in VS is because it is in Debug mode and that is not exactly how your code will behave when you Release it.